# (unordered) set container that has length that exceeds size_t in C++

Tags: c++, size, unordered-set

So I have an increasing sequence of objects (I can luckily convert each object to unique numbers possibly of range that is more than 32 bit). So without loss of generality let us assume I have a sequence of *int_64*. What do you do if you have a sequence that has length that exceeds *size_t* and you need to work with it as if you are working with (unordered) sets (i.e. do searches and avoid duplicates but ordering is not a big deal). Previously I worked with *boost::unordered_set* but this has max_size that is *size_t* .. is it possible to have a container (or even extend *boost::unodered_set*) such that it can hold more than *size_t* elements? If the sequence is too big, would it be more efficient if I just saved the sequence in a file and do a search in the file?

Comment: what exactly is your problem? efficiency? what kind of operations do you need to perform on your data?

Comment: my problem is that the usual containers that I am dealing with: e.g. std::set , boost::unordered_set etc. have a max_size that does not exceed a certain amount (say max of an int_32 value) but I have data with number of values that is more than this amount and I need a container for this data.

Comment: why do you require a `set` type? how about using an ordinary `vector`?

Comment: because I don't want duplicates and I sometimes get duplicates in my data and I want a fast search through a (luckily 1-1) hash function

Comment: data is inserted in the set iteratively and I need to know the exact size without duplicates.. and btw.. vectors have the same problem it can contain max of size_t number of objects

Comment: do you really need more than 2^60 elements? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96277e8fb3d9f7f2

Comment: Yes I do. I am counting something similar to a number of graphs with more than 12 nodes (not exactly this number but a number quite near to it) and this is done by an algorithm that increases the set until a certain iteration is acheived. A set of graphs with 12 nodes has 2^(6*11)=2^66 elements. And I could possibly increase the node which would make the data even more

Comment: 10^11 gigabytes seems a bit unpractical to me ...

Comment: How did this become 10^11 gigabytes? my objects are at most 8 bytes long

Comment: @quantum: Considering that you have at most 2^64 unique objects, and that `std::set` doesn't contain duplicates, **size_t is big enough** (assuming common 64 bits hardware)

Comment: @MSalters but I have more than 2^64 unique objects.

Comment: @quantum: No, you don't. It's mathematically impossible. Your 8 byte object contains 64 bits, and there are only 2^64 unique combinations of 64 bits. Consider `std::reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(your_object)`.

Comment: @MSalters I don't have it in the set of course which cannot contain all of it. It is mathematically possible it is just not possible to contain it in the std::set. 2^64+1 is greater than 2^64 but it exceeds the set size. I'm not talking about how many object the set can contain. I am talking about how many objects there exists which is just a combinatorial problem and not related to the computer. I cannot contain them even if I am able to create them hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

The container limit is a bit of a red herring: your system will run oitnof address space first.

If you want a library, stxxl has disk backed containers.  Or just use a sql or other kind of database.

---

If I had to, and I could not implement my own database or stxxl, I would hash down to a smaller size (say 24 bits) and keep up to N elements directly there.  When you need to know size, or the in memory elements are full, you read the table on disk for that 24 bit hash.

Maybe chain futures to calculate the full size, allowing async disk access to update the values and the 2^24 nodes.

Comment: yes, this is more or less what I was thinking of. More or less you will have to create your own data structure. Of course stxxl is an option but does it also support sets?